Recursive bounds on Ramsey numbers for $k>2$?
We know for two colours the a recursive upper bound for $R_2(p,q)$ can be written as,
$$R_2(p,q) \leq R_2(p-1,q) + R_2(p,q-1)$$
The proof goes like the following,
Proof:
It is enough to show that any two-colouring (say red and blue) of the edges of $K_M$ where $M = R_2(p,q-1) + R_2(p-1,q)$ yields a blue $p$-clique or a red $q$-clique.
We fix a vertex $v$ in $K_M$, the vertex is incident with $M-1 = R_2(p-1,q) + R_2(p,q-1) -1$ edges in $K_M$, by pigeon-hole principle we can say that either at least $R_2(p-1,q)$ edges are blue or $R_2(p,q-1)$ edges are red.
WLOG, let us assume the former happens (i.e at least  $R_2(p-1,q)$ edges are blue), Let $X$ be the set of all the vertices that are incident by these blue edges, Since $|X| \geq R_2(p-1,q)$, by definition this must contain blue $p-1$ clique, or a red $q$ clique.
If it's the latter (i.e a red $q$ clique) then we are done, but if it's the former then the graph formed by the set of vertices $X\   U \  \{v\}$, contains a  blue $p$ clique. $QED$.
And hence we can write, $R_2(p,q) \leq M$.
By induction on $p+q$, it can be easily shown that $R_2(p,q)$ exists for all $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can a similar recursive upper bound be shown for $R_k(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$, (i.e a k-colouring of a graph). So that the existence of $R_k(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$ can be shown by induction on $\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i$.


What is the planar-graphs tag for??

Hint: $$R_1(x)\le R_1(x-1)+1$$ $$R_2(x,y)\le R_2(x-1,y)+R_2(x,y-1)$$ $$R_3(x,y,z)\le R_3(x-1,y,z)+R_3(x,y-1,z)+R_3(x,y,z-1)-1$$

If you just want to show that $R_k(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ exists and don't care about getting halfway decent bounds, just observe that $R_3(n_1,n_2,n_3)\le R_2(n_1,R_2(n_2,n_3))$ etc.

Can you elaborate on the bounds part a bit?
